# Adding soft return in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How can I add a soft return in rich text box?

As I press in Microsoft Word <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, that the cursor move down to the next line, but it still same paragraph, and paragraph formatting also continued this text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a Vertical Tab `(char)11`.